# Blazor server app has Null Reference exception at line 0 on Windows 2016?

Tags: c#, blazor, httpcontext, windows-server-2016

I have a blazor server app trying to run on Windows 2016(w/IIS v10) and it throws up an error as shown below:

[image]

I have been unable to determine the cause of this.  This app runs on Windows Server 2012 and 2019.  This only happens on 2016.  I am not sure where to go with this as the error reads like this is an issue within a Microsoft library.

Has anyone see anything like this and found a resolution??

The TopMenuBar is a razor component

```
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
      foreach (var claim in ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims)
      {
        if (claim.Type == LSSClaimType.Name)
        {
            FullName = claim.Value;
            break;
        }
      }
      isDarkMode = await LocalStorage.GetAsync<bool>(StoredData.MyTheme);
      await base.OnInitializedAsync();
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: LSS.Application.Shared... does not look like a MS library. If it is not part of your code maybe it is a third party lib?

Comment: As @StefanFFM said, it is probably not a Microsoft library that is the source of your issue: you are probably trying to access a property or method from a null object in the `OnInitializedAsync` method of `TopMenuBar` component. This displays some error related to Microsoft libraries because in blazor components, `OnInitializedAsync` is inherited from `ComponentBase`.

Comment: TopMenuBar is a razor component and I added the code for the OnInitializedAsync method to my post.

Comment: In most cases, [do not use IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#avoid-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components) in razor components in Blazor Server.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine - Why is does this seem to only affect Windows Server 2016?

Comment: @Kixoka I don't know. _If_ it is the source of the exception, which I suspect but don't know for sure, `HttpContext` is unreliable but not always null. You might have unexpected data in `HttpContext` even if it is not null.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Part of the problem was due to a configuration of the server.  Web Sockets protocol needed to be enabled. Enabling this fixed the issue.